# Problems building with G++ on MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I'm a bit new to MATLAB but am currently trying to build MEX files using G++ (version 6.3) as the compiler. I got this error

```
MEX completed successfully.
Building with 'g++'.
Error using mex
/disks/local/sceneflow2/./external/libtrws/trwsMex.cpp:14:13: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef
int mwSize’
In file included from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include/matrix.h:25:0,
                 from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include/mex.h:51,
                 from /disks/local/sceneflow2/./external/libtrws/trwsMex.cpp:9:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:795:19: error: ‘mwSize’ has a previous
declaration as ‘typedef size_t mwSize’
/disks/local/sceneflow2/./external/libtrws/trwsMex.cpp:15:13: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef
int mwIndex’
In file included from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include/matrix.h:25:0,
                 from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include/mex.h:51,
                 from /disks/local/sceneflow2/./external/libtrws/trwsMex.cpp:9:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:796:19: error: ‘mwIndex’ has a previous
declaration as ‘typedef size_t mwIndex’


Error in make_mex (line 20)
mex ./external/libtrws/trwsMex.cpp -largeArrayDims CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -std=c++0x -fpermissive"
-outdir build
```

I don't get it. Why is `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include/tmwtypes.h` definition of `mwSize` conflicting with `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include/mex.h`? Aren't they predefined libraries included with MATLAB (meaning they should work fine?)

By the way, `/disks/local/sceneflow2/./external/libtrws/trwsMex.cpp` has a line which includes the aforementioned `mex.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message has to blocks (for two different errors), let's look at the first one only. I've split it out into three "lines":

> ```
> /disks/local/sceneflow2/./external/libtrws/trwsMex.cpp:14:13: error: conflicting declaration
> ‘typedef int mwSize’
>
> In file included from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include/matrix.h:25:0,
>                  from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include/mex.h:51,
>                  from /disks/local/sceneflow2/./external/libtrws/trwsMex.cpp:9:
>
> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/extern/include/tmwtypes.h:795:19: error: ‘mwSize’ has a previous
> declaration as ‘typedef size_t mwSize’
> ```

The first line says that the compiler found a declaration for `mwSize` on line 14 of your `trwsMex.cpp` file, where it says `typedef int mwSize`.

The last line says that this `mwSize` was already defined in the `tmwtypes.h` header that comes with MATLAB.

The second line says that this header file was included by `matrix.h`, which is included by `mex.h`, which is included by your `trwsMex.cpp` on line 9.

---

So, to fix the error, don't define `mwSize` and `mwIndex` in your MEX-file source code, these are defined by MATLAB's headers.